# How does one use showInputDialog to return an object from a dropdown?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have an object, let's call it catRancher, he has a catHerd(ArrayList), in my view I have a list that shows all his cats with a button that launches showInputDialog, what I want is a combobox with a big list of all possible cats on this catFarm, so that I can choose which cat to add to his herd from the farm.

I want something like this:

```
allCatsArray = catFarm.getAllCats().toArray();
Cat selectedCat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(appFrame, allCatsArray, "Which cat?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

catRancher.getCatHerd().add(selectedCat);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the following method, which returns an object, and not a String.

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType,
                                     Icon icon,
                                     Object[] selectionValues,
                                     Object initialSelectionValue)
                              throws HeadlessException
```

So your code may look like

```
Cat selectedCat = (Cat)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(appFrame, "title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, allCatsArray, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at The Java [JOptionPane API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) from "Getting the User's Input from a Dialog" on.
You are right, you have to create an JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...) like u allready did, this is the only one that returns an Object. And don't forget to cast the returning object to (in your case) Cat. This would look like:

```
Cat selectedCat = (Cat) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(appFrame, allCatsArray, "Which cat?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

And don't forget to check the "selectedCat" for NULL.